# Unit Tests Not Working - Ruby using test-unit

Tags: arrays, ruby, unit-testing, testing, testunit

I'm in the final stage of a simple project and I need my tests to start working. Basically, I am testing a function that sorts an array, and none of my tests are asserting. I'm using the test-unit gem in Ruby.

So I have three files:

```
program.rb (where the method is invoked and passed an array)
plant_methods.rb (where the class is defined with its class method)
tc_test_plant_methods.rb (where the test should be run)
```

Heres what's in each file:

```
plant_methods.rb
```

The purpose of plant_sort is to sort each sub-array alphabetically, using the first plant in the sub-array.

```
class Plant_Methods
  def initialize
  end

  def self.plant_sort(array) 
    array.sort! { |sub_array1, sub_array2|
      sub_array1[0] <=> sub_array2[0] }
  end
end
```

Here's the program file.

```
program.rb

require_relative 'plant_methods'

plant_array = [['Rose', 'Lily', 'Daisy'], ['Willow', 'Oak', 'Palm'], ['Corn', 'Cabbage', 'Potato']]

Plant_Methods.plant_sort(plant_array)
```

And here's the test unit.

```
tc_test_plant_methods.rb

require_relative "plant_methods"
require "test/unit"

class Test_Plant_Methods < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_plant_sort
      puts " it sorts the plant arrays alphabetically based on the first plant"
    assert_equal([["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"], ["Violet", "Sunflower"]], Plant_Methods.new([["Violet", "Sunflower"], ["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"]]).plant_sort([["Violet", "Sunflower"], ["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"]]))
  end

end
```

However, when I run tc_test_plant_methods.rb, I get the following errors:

```
$ ruby tc_plant_methods.rb 
Run options: 
# Running tests:

[1/1] Test_Plant_Methods#test_plant_sort it sorts the plant arrays alphabetically based on the first plant
 = 0.00 s
  1) Error:
test_plant_sort(Test_Plant_Methods):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

And

```
Finished tests in 0.003687s, 271.2232 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

So basically the test runs, but it doesn't return any assertions. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong, or how to fix this?

Comment: Just to remember, Princess @Leia_Organa, tests are not for final stage! They are at the very begining. Write tests first, write code later!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a class method, you should call it like

```
Plant_Methods.plant_sort([["Violet", "Sunflower"],
                         ["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"]])
```

not like

```
Plant_Methods.new([["Violet", "Sunflower"], ["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"]])\
             .plant_sort([["Violet", "Sunflower"], ["Gingko", "Beech"], ["Rice", "Wheat"]])
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is the exact answer I needed to make all my tests work!